# failed loading zone from 'myzone.local.zone': no ttl

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, debian, dnssec

I run the following command for dnssec on debian 8. But I get error:

```
# dnssec-signzone -A -3 $(head -c 1000 /dev/random | sha1sum | cut -b 1-16) -N INCREMENT -o myzone.local -t myzone.local.zone
dnssec-signzone: warning: Kmyzone.local.+007+16956.key:5: no TTL specified; zone rejected
dnssec-signzone: fatal: failed loading zone from 'myzone.local.zone': no ttl
```

Comment: had this command worked successfully for you previously? Are the key includes at the tail end of the zone?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you also got stuck on the [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-dnssec-on-an-authoritative-bind-dns-server--2#dnssec-master-configuration).

So if you created your KSK and ZSK with the `dnssec-keygen`, you should have used the `-L` flag to set the TTL in the files, like this:

```
# dnssec-keygen -L 3600 -a NSEC3RSASHA1 -b 2048 -n ZONE example.com
# dnssec-keygen -L 3600 -f KSK -a NSEC3RSASHA1 -b 2048 -n ZONE example.com
```

This argument might not have been required (defaulted to 3600?) when the tutorial was written.

If you've already generated the files, I think you can just edit them (both named `Kexample.com.*.key`).  Just add "3600" before "IN" on the line with the record.  So from:

```
Khexample.com.+008+27593.key:example.com. IN DNSKEY 256 3 8 <key>
```

to:

```
Khexample.com.+008+27593.key:example.com. 3600 IN DNSKEY 256 3 8 <key>
```

I'm not sure if 3600 is a good value or not, but that's what the tutorial author [recommended](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-dnssec-on-an-authoritative-bind-dns-server--2?comment=48313).  My other source was `man dnssec-keygen`.